# COUNT() behave in different ways

Tags: php, mysql, count

I wrote the code and it worked on my local wamp server. **count(A.id) or $count was 1** and everything was ok. I uploaded that file and went to the real website and **$count was 3 although databases were the same**(identical records).

I changed:

COUNT(A.id)  >>>>  **(SELECT COUNT(id) FROM table1 WHERE lower(login_name)=lower(?))**
$stmt->bind_param('s',$get_user); >>>> **$stmt->bind_param('ss',$get_user, $get_user);**
and that solved the problem. $count became 1. Can someone explain me why this happened.

Of course, the query should select one record from the database depending on the username given in $_GET['name']

```
$db = new mysqli($DBhost, $DBuser, $DBpassword, $DBdatabase);
$query = "SELECT COUNT(A.id), A.profile_public, A.id, A.login_name, A.user_title, A.user_title_color, A.banner, A.banner_position, A.registration_date, A.priv, A.ban, A.block, A.special_user, B.birth, B.birth_change, B.birth_pub, B.age, B.age_change, B.age_pub, B.country, B.country_change, B.country_pub, A.email, B.email_pub, A.movie_suggestions, A.accepted_suggestions, B.reputation, COUNT(C.movie), A.fav_pub, B.gender, B.gender_pub, B.gender_change, B.social, B.social_pub, B.social_change, B.about FROM table1 AS A LEFT JOIN table2 AS B ON A.id=B.userid LEFT OUTER JOIN table3 AS C ON A.login_name=C.user WHERE lower(A.login_name)=lower(?)";
$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param('s',$get_user);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($count, $public, $id, $lg_name, $user_title, $user_title_color, $banner, $banner_position, $registration_date, $privs, $usr_ban, $block, $special_user, $birth, $birth_change, $birth_pub, $age, $age_change, $age_pub, $country, $country_change, $country_pub, $email, $email_pub, $movie_suggestions, $accepted_suggestions, $reputation, $count_favorites, $fav_pub, $gender, $gender_pub, $gender_change, $social1, $social_pub, $social_change, $about);
$stmt->fetch();
```

Comment: if you're query was the same on both servers, then it had to be the DB since PHP doesn't change db entries such as the id. there were times i thought i had the same db copy but in reality i had something completely different until I did a dump, delete on the 2nd db and db reload.

Comment: @unixmiah It can be but I'm completely sure. If it was about databases, why it started working when I changed the code? And if databases are identical, COUNT should behave the same way on both servers, and $count always should be 1 but thanks anyways, it could be that.